# Please delete misspelled (ananlysis) tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-management, spelling

Please delete the incorrectly spelled [ananlysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ananlysis) tag, which was accidentally used yesterday in https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/993170/1.

(I would have flagged this tag if possible, but I don't see any way to do that.  So therefore I'm doing a meta question.)

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/deleting-tags-after-being-created

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as no questions use the tag when the automatic script next runs (about 03:00UTC every day), it will automatically be removed from the system.  (See [this MSE thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/214632).) Until then, there is nothing we can do except remove it if it happens to be added to more questions.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: I sped this along by manually merging the tags. Enjoy!

Comment: @Haney: I'll have to remember that trick. Thanks!