# Tag management 2023-present

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

New year, new tag management thread.

Rules of the game are basically [the same](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31103/446262):

- Post your suggestion as an answer here if you see

  - A particularly bad tag (a rule of thumb: “if I can't imagine a person classifying a tag as either interesting or ignored, I'm getting rid of it”),
  - A tag that should be a synonym of an existing one,
  - A tag that used for two or more completely unrelated things,
  - A need to create a new tag.
- Upvote/downvote/comment as your agree/disagree with suggestions, so please post different suggestions in separate answers.
- Wait a couple of days before implementing a suggestion.
- After the problem described in an answer is resolved, please edit it to say so.
- If your tag suggestion exists in a separate question, please provide a link to the question in your suggestion.

See also:

- The [list with pending and approved synonyms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).
- The [tagging chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/tagging) for extended discussion on tagging.
- [Last year's thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34525/446262) to look for suggestions that need to be implemented.

Also, note that one may use `[tag:calculus]` for [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus), i.e. tags on the main site, and `[meta-tag:discussion]` for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), i.e. for tags on the meta site.

Note that, in some cases, it might be better to have a separate question. Typically this happens when a longer discussion is needed and several possible answers are expected, since answers to a question provide more space for a more detailed discussion than comments under an answer in this thread.

Previous tag management threads:

- [Tag management 2022](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34525/)
- [Tag management 2021](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32974/)
- [Tag management 2020](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31103/)
- [Tag management 2019](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29718/)
- [Tag management 2018](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27653/)
- [Tag management 2017](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25694/)
- [Tag management 2016](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22348/)
- [Tag management 2015](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/)
- [Tag cleanup 2014](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12485/)

Comment: I will just mention that the list in the question will show a pending synonym only to users with sufficient score to vote for (or against) the synonym. Still, one can get list of all pending synonyms from SEDE: [main](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1239539/pending-tag-synonyms), [meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.math/query/1239539/pending-tag-synonyms). (Keeping in mind that the database is only updated once a week.)

Answer (score 20):

**Proposal:** Delete tag  [math-school](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-school).

This is a useless tag. It is only on [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4629024) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4619548) and is reminiscent of the old 'homework' tag.

Comment: Actually, the tags called (math-school) and (school-math) have been created and removed [a few times already](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?room=3740&q=math+school).

Comment: I edited it off those questions. It should be gone soon.

Answer (score 9):

I propose the tag Fractional-differential-equations (FDE). They are increasingly becoming important. To give a flavor of its importance I'm including an article in which the Covid pandemic was studied with FDE: [Application of piecewise fractional differential equation to COVID-19 infection dynamics - 2022 - Xiao-Ping Li et.al.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/35694036/)

The tags ordinary-differential equation, and partial-differential-equation already exist. Some fractional calculus questions do not deal with fractional differential equations, while other questions do, therefore showing the difference is important. Second, I had to tag my question [Fractional Bernoulli equation and logistic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4636648/fractional-bernoulli-equation-and-logistic-function) with the incorrect tag ordinary-differential-equation, to explain that the question dealt with differential equations; but the tag I added is misleading if one is searching for the subject of fractional differential equations and excludes questions dealing with ordinary differential equations.

Suggestion for Tag excerpt is: Everything involving fractional calculus (FC) differential equations: in practical application of FC differential equations; in pure mathematics; numerical methods for the resolution of FDE; dynamical systems; fractional partial differential equations; FDE of distributed order; boundary value problems for FDE; techniques for studying FDE; in a variety of subjects ranging from mathematical physics to probability theory.

Perhaps my suggestion could be split in two, using the extensive enumeration of problems for the wiki.

Comment: What's next? I can't create it myself.

Comment: Right, that privilege [requires 1000 reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).  I've taken up your request in the tagging chatroom.  There are already forty posts that combine fractional-calculus and ordinary-differential-equations tags, so I'm inclined to accept that a critical mass of material can benefit from your new tag.  I'll keep you informed.

Comment: If creation of this tag is considered, do you have a suggestion what the [tag-excerpt and the tag-wiki](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-wikis/info) should look like. (If you do have some suggestion, you could include it in your answer - or at least edit them after the tag is created.) BTW here is a link to a few related comment [in the tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/tag-for-fractional-differential-equations).

Comment: @MartinSleziak, I've edited the answer to include excerpt and wiki suggestions, yesterday. How long does the process of adding a new tag take? How do I find out? Or do I have to try editing each day my post to see if the tag is available?

Comment: The tag [tag:fractional-differential-equations] has been created, using your suggested text for the tag excerpt.  I also wrote up a tag wikia with some links to definitions, etc.  It seems to me that the new tag should not exclude tags for ordinary differential equations or partial differential equations, since fractional derivatives may  arise in either univariate or multivariate contexts (and my wikia text reflects that).

Comment: @hardmath, you're right, re ODE and PDE. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 9):

**Proposal**:  Add tag `witt-vectors`.

There are [quite a few](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22witt+vectors%22+is%3Aquestion) existing questions about Witt vectors, and most of them are tagged with some combination of [abstract-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra), [commutative-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commutative-algebra), [p-adic-number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-adic-number-theory), [algebraic-number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-number-theory), [algebraic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-geometry), and so on.  Witt vectors are a rather specific construction, so I don't feel that any of these generic tags really does these questions justice.

Answer (score 9):

> **Proposal:** Either delete and blacklist the tag [differential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential) or make it a synonym of [derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivatives)

It seems that the tag is used for (1) derivatives or (2) accidentally while trying to type a longer tag such as [ordinary-differential-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordinary-differential-equations) or [differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry) or (3) "infinitesimal" differentials. The tag wiki is about multivariate derivatives. This tag was already a problem [in 2015](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21208/32766). There are [1500+ questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential?tab=Newest) with the tag [differential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential) and [150+ questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/429381/find-questions-with-one-specific-tag?tag=differential) of those have no other tags. [Another 64](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential%2bgeometry?tab=Newest), as of now, are tagged with [differential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential) and [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) which probably also need to be retagged.

After going through the oldest 125 questions, the situation seems to be worse than I thought. About 3/4 should be split about half-and-half between differential-equations (mostly ordinary but some partial) and derivatives. The [derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivatives) would probably not be completely misplaced on many of the differential equations questions, especially since almost all of them *are* properly tagged with [ordinary-differential-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordinary-differential-equations) or [partial-differential-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partial-differential-equations), but it also doesn't seem super relevant. Most of the other 1/4 also could take [derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivatives) but are probably better suited to [differential-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-topology), [differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-geometry) or [differential-forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-forms).

Around 10% of the 125 questions I went through are actually about possible definitions of differentials, line elements etc. I do think it makes sense to tag these with [derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivatives) but maybe some version of the [differential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential) tag is worth keeping around. @MJD suggested [differentials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differentials) for a rename.

Comment: Oldest was more convenient than sampling randomly, and obvious caveats: (1) I had to use my subjective judgment (2) no clue how well these proportions approximate those for all 1500+ questions.

Comment: What if [tag:differential] were renamed to [tag:differentials]?

Comment: @MJD I like that as the tag for questions about differentials. But only renaming won't solve the "differential geometry" problem.

Comment: I agree it doesn't solve all problems. But it solves some. And I think we do need a tag for it, because it is a topic that comes up regularly.

Comment: Surveying questions _with_ the tag is necessarily going to be biased against questions where the tag is appropriate. That methodology ignores all the questions that should have the tag but don't.  For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200393/what-is-dx-in-integration and most of the 52 (!!) questions linked to it should have the [tag:differentials] tag.  But only two of them do have this tag.

Comment: @MJD That's a very good point. But that exhibits an even greater discrepancy between how the tag *is* used and how it's "meant to be" used. Maybe if we rename it to "differentials", we can also mention it in the [tag:infinitesimals] wiki?

Comment: I don't know what I think is the best thing to do here. I'm skeptical that anyone reads tag wikis.

Answer (score 7):

I propose that [coercive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coercive) ⟶ [coercive-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coercive-functions) **or** [coercive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coercive) ⟶ [coercivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coercivity).

Comment: I like "coercive-functions"; that's the first tag I'd try searching for if I were posting a related question. When I taught this material a few years ago, I'm pretty sure the word "coercivity" never came out of my mouth.

Answer (score 6):

**Proposal:** Make a synonym [linear-fractional-transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-fractional-transformation) $\to$ [mobius-transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-transformation).

Both tags are about the same topic, namely functions of the form $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with $a, b, c, d \in \Bbb C$.

[mobius-transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobius-transformation) has

- a more detailed tag info,
- more questions in total (817 vs 47)
- more questions this year (78 vs 11)

therefore it should be the synonym target.

**Update:** The tag synonym has been approved by a [moderator](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/468350/xander-henderson) and is now active.

Comment: Here are links to related excahnges in the [Math Mods' Office](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/20352/2023/12/8) and [Tagging](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2023/12/8).

Answer (score 5):

Proposal: Delete [complex-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-spaces). I just created this tag but Elliot Yu pointed out rightly in a comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4640382/394668) that it is ambiguous. To solve this, I just created the better tag [complex-analytic-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analytic-spaces), which is unambiguous. Because of the existence of the latter, the former doesn't serve any purpose anymore.

Comment: Seems redundant with the tag complex-geometry which already exists.

Comment: Since you have already [removed the tag from your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4640382/revisions). the tag should be gone in the next 24 hours. (Unless somebody else uses the tag - which seems unlikely.) See also: [Deleting Tags after being created](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1200) and [Please delete misspelled (ananlysis) tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17170).

Answer (score 4):

The tag [solution-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification) is quite misleading, and that's why we have seen a lot of questions end with "Is my solution correct?"

We have also seen this type of question come out to be an exact duplicate of some other post.

Verification of an open-ended question is a threat to the site's policy and shouldn't be encouraged. So I think it's now time to discuss the tag [solution-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification).

My recommendation is to replace the tag by a better one that emphasises the meaning of the tag in a better way, and that forces OP to think about the end line as "is the $\underline{}$ step correct?" or "have I applied the result, theorem, or lemma in the $\underline{}$ step correctly?"
To expect more specificity, we should make our tag more specific.

[solution-step-verfication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-step-verfication) or [n-th-step-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/n-th-step-verification)

Comment: I have also use it when my question got an answer I don't fully understand, so I asked other users to validate it through their upvotes using that tag. I think is useful in both ways (this one and the way you mentioned).

Answer (score 4):

[Hoare logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic) is a well-defined topic in the study of computer program semantics.

- [31 posts match `Hoare logic`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=hoare+logic)
- [13 posts match `Hoare triple`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=hoare+logic)
- [19 posts match `postcondition precondition`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=postcondition+precondition)

There is considerable overlap here, but I didn't look closely.

I think it would be worth my time to create a [hoare-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hoare-logic) tag and put it on these posts, but I want to make sure there is not some other suitable tag already, and that others don't think it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

**Proposal**: Make a synonym [finite-state-machine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-state-machine) → [automata](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automata), as has been done already with [finite-automata](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-automata).

- [finite-automata](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-automata) is a synonym for [automata](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automata)

  - There are over 2000 questions with this tag
- [finite-state-machine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finite-state-machine) is separate

  - There are only 77 questions with this tag
  - Of those, 24 also have the [automata](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automata) tag
  - The [automata](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automata) tag is appropriate for the content of most of the others too

Comment: Is it a synonym, though?

Comment: No, it's actually a subtopic, just as [tag:finite-automata] is a subtopic of [tag:automata].  But it's a small enough subtopic that it doesn't need its own tag, and should be handled with the site's synonym feature.

Comment: Is it a subtopic?  When I think of finite automata, I think of strings and languages.  When I think of FSMs, I think of coffee machines.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the use of the tag on the main site is nearly always in connection with automata and formal languages, even counting out the 25 questions that are also tagged with [tag:automata].

Answer (score 4):

I propose the tag [dyadic-decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dyadic-decomposition) or something similar involving the word ``dyadic'' (e.g. [dyadic-approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dyadic-approximation), etc.). It is one of the most important techniques in analysis (especially harmonic analysis). For instance, I wanted to use it in my question [Dyadic sum of $\frac{x}{\ln x}$ (i.e. dyadic asymptotic for prime number theorem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4875394/dyadic-sum-of-fracx-ln-x-i-e-dyadic-asymptotic-for-prime-number-theorem). There are many questions on the site already that are about this concept: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=dyadic.

Answer (score 2):

Proposal: Make [dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dice) a synonym of [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability). All problems about this are sure to be about expected value or probability.

Comment: I created a tag synonym proposal for this.

Comment: Why did people downvote the tag-synonym?

Comment: If a question about dice is about probability, it should tagged **probability**. **Dice** is just a funny unnecessary additional tag, like **Cards** or **Coins**. I think there is nothing wrong in it given it is not used instead of **probability**.

Comment: There are some 100K questions with the tag [tag:probability]. Why not use [tag:dice] to narrow things down?  Moreover, have you tried [searching](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcombinatorial-game-theory%5D+dice) for `[combinatorial-game-theory] dice`?

Answer (score 2):

**Proposal:** Add tag `dual-numbers`.

Although the [dual numbers](https://Although%20the%20dual%20numbers%20are%20a%20well-known%20hypercomplex%20number%20system,%20there%20is%20no%20tag%20for%20the%20dual%20numbers%20in%20SE.%20As%20far%20as%20I%27ve%20seen%20so%20far,%20there%20are%20no%20synonyms%20for%20dual%20numbers.) are a well-known [hypercomplex number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_types_of_numbers), there is no tag for the dual numbers in SE *(e.g. for [this Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4563339/how-to-take-the-square-root-of-a-dual-number-sqrta-b-cdot-varepsilon-w))*. As far as I've seen so far, there are no [synonyms for dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_types_of_numbers) too.

Comment: Probably it is worth pointing out that the tag (dual-numbers) was created and removed a few times in the past. I was able to find four questions, they are listed [in the tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62893079#62893079). (I think that the most recent one was precisely [the question you linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4563339/revisions).)

Answer (score 1):

Proposal: Make [birthday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birthday) a synonym of [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability). All problems about this are sure to be about expected value or probability.

Comment: Some older posts related to the tag (birthday): [The birthday tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27389) and [Tag merging and synonyms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1363#1975).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I created a tag synonym proposal for this.

Comment: I see, maybe you should include a link [to the list of proposed synonyms for problability](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/probability/synonyms). In the [list of all tag synonyms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) on can see that it was proposed in December 2022. The same information can be obtained [from SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1178483/data-about-a-tag-synonym?tagname=birthday).

Comment: @mathlander, did you see the "Wait a couple of days before implementing a suggestion" in the rules?

Comment: @PeterPhipps As far as I can tell, the OP suggested the synonym already on December 2 - about two months before this post. It seems that in the meantime, the suggestion was downvoted to $-2$ and removed. (But it was there today - and it is still shown in SEDE.)

Comment: Again, I think this is unwise.  There are 100K questions with the tag [tag:probability].  Making questions harder to find via synonymization is regress, not progress.

Answer (score 1):

Given the existence of the tag [np-complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/np-complete), I propose that the tag [np-hard](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/np-hard) be **created**.

Comment: I think it should be one or the other but not both.  Any NP-completeness result necessarily includes a proof of NP-hardess.  Nobody looking for NP-hardness results is going to be please that their search results omit posts that happen to be tagged [tag:np-complete].

Answer (score 1):

Since searching for `sinc` yields nearly $1500$ [results](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=sinc), I propose that the tag [cardinal-sine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardinal-sine) be created for the [cardinal sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) function

$$ \operatorname{sinc} (x) := \frac{\sin (x)}{x} $$

Comment: I think the name  “cardinal sine” is not well-known.  Why wouldn't the tag be [tag:sinc]?

Comment: @MJD I do **not** object to [tag:sinc]. When I learned signal processing, the professors called it [cardinal sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function). There is also the [raised cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raised-cosine_filter)

Comment: sinc is probably better known, but indeed I too learned about the cardinal sine in signal processing. And it's what the "c" of sinc means. I tend to prefer cardinal-sine as it's more explicit.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I am tempted to conclude that Angloids use "sinc" and Latinoids use "cardinal sine"

Comment: I have studied electric engineering in Latam, and I have used the sinc function a lot, and this is the first time I saw it named "cardinal sine" (I guess here teachers come from an English background, due their postgraduate schools are typically from USA or England).

Answer (score 1):

Since the tag [smooth-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smooth-functions) deals mainly with analytical ones, I would like to propose some tag or synonyms for grouping questions related to [smooth bump functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) which are [non-analytical real-valued smooth functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) of compact support interesting enough just by themselves on how to built them (are plenty of related questions), but also their relation to [distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory) as examples of [test functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaces_of_test_functions_and_distributions), also its relation with [Mollifiers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) used to built [weak-derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weak-derivatives), are related also as examples of functions in the [schwartz-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schwartz-space), or used to make [Partition of unity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity) on [sobolev-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sobolev-spaces)... as also their relation with completeley unrelated topics like how the example of the [Rvachëv function](https://oeis.org/A288163) solves the [delay-differential-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delay-differential-equations) $r'(x)=2\ r(2x+1)-2\ r(2x-1)$.

As could you see no existent tag fully relates to them but only on their possible individual applications, thats why I think a tag for "Mollifers" or "Test Functions" or "Smooth Bump Functions" having the others as synonyms could be helpfull.
As example, if [I search on MSE about "bump functions"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=bump+functions) it shows about 1720 questions which tags are quite unrelated with the main topic they are asking for: characteristics of these non-analytic smooth functions with compact support.

Or at least, introduce this synonyms in the tag [smooth-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smooth-functions) in order to carry "viewers" that could answer these related questions.

Comment: Huh?  What makes you think that the smooth-functions tag is mainly about analytic functions?  Looking over the questions that use the tag almost all of them are about smooth functions that are not necessarily analytic.

Comment: @EricWofsey I have made recently a few really basic questions about basic examples of bump functions without getting answers, as example.

Comment: @EricWofsey by the way, knowing the politics for tags are restrictive, I aim to ask for introducing the mentioned terms as synonyms in the tag smooth-functions. I don't have enough reputation to do it by myself (by far).

Answer (score 1):

Add tag [zonogon](/questions/tagged/zonogon)

Zonogons are polygons that have pairs of parallel sides with the same length. There are several examples where this might be used, like [2D different integer valued vertices coordinates of cube projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4743674/2d-different-integer-valued-vertices-coordinates-of-cube-projection/4743801#4743801), [Orthogonal Projection Area of a 3D Cuboid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740897/orthogonal-projection-area-of-a-3d-cuboid), [Finding the dimensions of a box (cuboid) given a hexagon filled in to look like the box](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4707792/finding-the-dimensions-of-a-box-cuboid-given-a-hexagon-filled-in-to-look-like), [Why are parallelograms defined as quadrilaterals? What term would encompass polygons with greater than two parallel pairs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220273/why-are-parallelograms-defined-as-quadrilaterals-what-term-would-encompass-poly) and there is even one about them on Mathematica.stackexchange: [How to create a random zonogon?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287922/how-to-create-a-random-zonogon)

Considering how specific these shapes are and how common they appear, could we have a tag for them? I intend to ask more questions about them in the future as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Proposal:** add tag `algebraic-identities`

I know that there is already a tag `algebraic-equations` which is
used for solving polynomial equations. That is, finding values of
the variables which make the equations true. However, an algebraic identity is true for all values of the variables, and so there is
nothing to find. In fact, algebraic identities are often used to
solve algebraic equations. Having a tag specifically for algebraic
identities would make it feasible to efficiently find questions which
involve algebraic identities for their statement or for their
solution. I often use algebraic identities in my answers if possible,
and I am always looking for new algebraic identities to add to my
collection of almost $800$ of them. I recently found a new algebraic
identity from the question

> [Show that $\frac {1}{\sqrt{5}}[(\frac {1}{x+r_+}) - (\frac {1}{x+r_-}) = \frac {1}{\sqrt{5}x}[(\frac {1}{1-r_{+}x}) - (\frac {1}{1-r_{-}x})] $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2359755)

Just now I noticed that the three tags `trigonometric-equations`,
`trigonometric-functions`, and `trigonometric-identities` have $0$
questions associated with them. Perhaps this is because they are
easily confused with each other and also perhaps because questions
with these tags are now tagged under `trigonometry` as synonyms instead.
I hope to avoid this problem for `algebraic-identities` by a more
careful description of which questions it would be appropriate for.

**EDIT** Mar 9, 2024:
For an alternative viewpoint I just visited
[AoPS Online](https://artofproblemsolving.com/)
and did a Tag search for identities. It returned

- identities
- trig identities
- Trigonometric Identities
- algebraic identities
- log identities
- binomial identities

---

By the way, the help center page
[create tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)
makes no mention of this meta thread which is why I created this
tag without discussion first, although, in hindsight, it makes sense
to have some moderation in the creation of new tags.

Comment: The [tag description](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-identities) mentions answers using algebraic identities, but tags are usually for the content of the questions

Comment: @ТymaGaidash True, usually for the content of questions. However, usually is not always. Maybe the purpose of tags can be stretched to include answers also. I think it could, but I could be wrong.

Comment: BTW the tag (algebraic-identities) was created and deleted several times before. You can find past occurrences from the [SEDE queries in the Tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2024/2/26). 
Here is a link to suggestion to remove the tag [back in 2016](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22414).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for that information! I did not know that before. I will have to read about this and learn from it. It is unfortunate that the tag is misapplied. Perhaps limiting it to polynomial algebraic identities only would help prevent that.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash: With respect to *“tags are usually for the content of the questions”* – I generally agree, but a different opinion is expressed here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2613/42969.

Comment: Just to clarify, the tags (trigonometric-equations), (trigonometric-functions), and (trigonometric-identities) are [synonyms of the tag trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/trigonometry/synonyms).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for that information! I now know that they are synonyms which explains my observation.

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the need for this tag.  How is it going to help to organize the site?  What kind of *questions* fit within the scope of this tag?  Which of those questions are not already well covered by other tags (e..g the [tag:algebra-precalculus] tag)?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for that comment! You don't see the need, but other people may have a different point of view. Questions which ask about the use of  algebraic identities in proofs, for example. I don't see how this is related or limited to precalculus. Its purpose is to identify questions which depend on or develop special algebraic identities such as those in my collection.

Comment: Since you are proposing the flag, it is up to you to convince other users that the tag is necessary.  Thus far, you have basically said "Some people might find it useful."  This is not a very powerful argument...

Comment: @XanderHenderson What are examples of "powerful arguments" in your opinion?

Comment: I think that it is worth pointing out that the parallel tag, [tag:trigonometric-identities], is a synonym of [tag:trigonometry]---there is no real utility for such a tag, and it has been subsumed by another.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I mentioned this in my proposal already except the "no real utility" part.

Answer (score -1):

**Proposal:** add tag `monotonicity`

I often encounter problems that require proving or finding the conditions for a function or sequence to be increasing, decreasing, or monotonic. For example, I recently asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4837178/how-to-prove-that-fx-frac-cot-frac-pix1-cot-frac-pix-cd) about proving that a function is strictly decreasing for $x>2$.

However, when I want to tag these questions, I am not sure what tag to use. The closest tag I found is [monotone-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monotone-functions), and I didn't find a tag specifically for proving monotonicity, and I realised that there are many question on this site that deal with monotonicity for functions and sequences  .

[monotone-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monotone-functions) has two problems: the first is it doesn’t include questions about proving sequences to be monotone and the second one is that the description is too vague and broad. When I ask a question that is only concerned with monotonicity, this tag doesn’t seem to be what I want.

I think there should be a tag for this, because there are many questions related to it. There is already a tag for [minima-maxima](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minima-maxima), which is a related topic, so why not a tag for monotonicity?

Comment: The goal of tags is to help classify posts so that they can be more easily found.  My prediction is that a [tag:monotonicity] tag is going to cause confusion:  monotonic functions are a subject of study in introductory mathematics classes (particularly calculus and analysis), and the users who ask questions about monotonic functions tend not to be the most sophisticated, and often won't understand the distinction between a [tag:monotonic-functions] tag and a [tag:monotonicity] tag.  Thus my guess is that these users will treat these tags equivalently.

Comment: Moreover, a monotone sequence *is* a function---every sequence is a function.  So the [tag:monotone-functions] tag *does* include such sequences.  And, addressing your second complaint, if you believe that the tag wiki is unclear, suggest an edit.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I don't really understand how is the tag wiki of  monotonic-functions helpful it is the definition of monotonic functions and I didn't find that very helpful  any other tag wiki like calculus for example  describe what type of questions to  tag them with this tag not the definition of the subject

Comment: @XanderHenderson one suggestion is 

Questions about proving or finding the conditions for a function to be increasing, decreasing, or monotonic. This tag may also include questions about applications or consequences of monotonicity, such as convergence, optimization, or inequalities.

Comment: I believe that, with 2k+ XP on this site, you have more than enough reputation to suggest edits to the tag wiki yourself.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I edited the tag but I have a suggestion to replace the name of monotonic-functions by  monotonicity  if possible ,what do you think ?

Comment: I have listed some past tags related to monotone sequences [in the tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/a-tag-for-monotone-sequences). As you can see, in all instances such tags have been removed relatively quickly.

Answer (score -7):

I think that at least 1 new tag for questions based on **Bourbaki's math' treatises** is needed, especially for their *measure theory* which is practically another subject than what is found under that title elsewhere. This is not always a problem, but it can be, due to different definitions - one can often "*identify*" corresponding concepts, but this may be invalid in some cases.

Too bad that there are still so many anti-bourbaki-ists among mathematicians. I myself am not a Bourbaki fanatic but appreciate much of their *publications* (Bourbaki is not an individual but a name for a group of mathematicians with variable membership, they publish in French) - not being a fanatic I sometimes want to study math' literature based on foundations possibly conflicting with Bourbaki's, and then I may have problems to "integrate" such literature with what I learned from Bourbaki. This is especially the case with measure theory which is never a simple thing. That's why it happens that if one of my questions gets attention, I can receive answers / comments not fitting my needs and when I indicate that I am using other definitions, the potential answerers lack the needing bases, so I get no usable answer. While on the other hand *people with a Bourbaki background* - if there are at all some using this site ... despite the language barrier which might also play a role - *will not look into my questions* if they have no reason to think I might have a compatible background.

Without a corresponding tag I have to mention this background in the title of such questions. I have already edited the title of one of them (call it X) - for which I eventually found and published myself an answer. In my opinion this justifies the creation of Bourbaki-related tags, especially one like [Bourbaki-measure-theory] ... I cannot do this myself, not having yet the priviledge needed. The already mentioned Q&A item X could be used to create the new tag. If my idea gets a priori approval I'll produce content for the description of the tag.

Comment: My proposal has been immediately been down-voted. Is this a *rational* reaction or one based on *hate* of Bourbaki?

Comment: Can you expand on why mentioning this in the title is insufficient? Titles are generally more widely read than the tags, and being clear about the setup for problems here at MSE is something that we already encourage quite a lot.

Comment: The tag (bourbaki) was created and removed in the past, I have posted some statistics [in the Tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2023/2/8). There is [a related post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22983) in an older tag management thread. (And there was a separate question today - now deleted: [I want at least one new tag for questions specific to Bourbaki's math' treatises, especially measure theory](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35485).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak the target of the last links (a now deleted question) was mine. After receiving a duplicate mention and realizing that I was supposed to enter my proposal here (and doing this) I deleted that myself. From another of your links, I found written: "The tag [bourbaki] is entirely useless. It gives nothing that searching "Bourbaki" doesn't already do". How is such a search done? Is it only finding Bourbaki when mentioned in a title? And who might do that? IMHO the same argument might apply to all tags ... so why tags at all? (continued)

Comment: I take the opportunity to mention that I did not find how to search for 2+ tags at the same time (combined with AND) Is this possible, if yes, how is it done? Same question for a tag and a non-tag word

Comment: @KReiser I will not answer your question for the moment, because I logically wait for answers to the two comments I just made

Comment: @UlysseKeller The basics of searching are unrelated to the discussion here - in order to avoid a long discussion unrelated to this topic, I posted some examples of possible searches [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62941795#62941795).

Comment: "My proposal has been immediately been down-voted. Is this a rational reaction or one based on hate of Bourbaki?" Votes on meta work differently.  An upvote means "I agree with this suggestion," while a downvote means "I disagree with this suggestion".  Downvotes on meta have no effect on reputation.  There is no reason to read "hate" into these votes.

Comment: @KReiser My little question to Martin a few comments above got no answer yet. I mean this: *IMHO the same argument might apply to all tags ... so why tags at all?* Once this is answered, I will be able to form a new opinion on your Q. *Can you expand on why mentioning this in the title is insufficient?* (or not - depending on that answer)

Comment: @XanderHenderson I clearly said "hate of *Bourbaki*" not of my person. Don't identify me with B.

Comment: There are issues of scale here. It's good to separate analysis and algebra by tag: they are large, distinct areas of math where many people will want to look at one instead of the other. Sometimes, as the resolution increases, this can be a more interesting ask - do we need to separate questions on Dummit and Foote's algebra text versus Fraleigh's algebra text? Probably not. Where does your request fall on this continuum and why?

Comment: @KReiser May-be a Bourbaki tag is really useless for nearly every situation where Bourbaki plays a role. BUT the case of *measure theory* is special: Bourbaki's and the classical MTs are like two different theories because at the start they differ wildly and much has to be done until what comes later is *more or less* the same. At the base the terminologies are *not* compatible; this problem ends only once the theories allow identifications (an abuse of language normally accepted because it simplifies things). But here things are not even 1 to 1 (continued)

Comment: (my last comment cont.) Bourbaki-style measures on a given l. c. space build a vector space. The difference of two positive measures in (say) Halmos may not exist. You can't even say that for $\mu$ = the Lebesgue measure on the real line, then $\mu - \mu = 0$ ... because this difference is undefined due to the *essentially* undefined charachter of oo - oo. And some Bourbaki-style non >=0 or complex measures have no counterpart in Halmos-style. This could be solved by some changes on the Halmos side, but this might be even more complicated than I first thought due to a detail I found @ Halmos

Comment: @UlysseKeller I do not think that you should read *any* hate into the downvotes, either for yourself, or for Bourbaki.  That simply isn't what votes here mean.

Comment: The problem ImhO are other people knowing Bourbaki - espec. their measure theory (MT) - who'd look here for answers & give answers ONLY IF they know that Bourbaki MT is ALSO a theme here (I think esp. about French lang. people with sufficient English-knowledge) ... the any way little chances would be better if they see a tag like say [Bourbaki-measure] ... after what has already been discussed here I don't imagine getting a general Bourbaki tag but only 1 for MT, for which it is like ANOTHER SUBJECT altogether (not the name B. is what matters but the special subject best described by using it)