# request for a new tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

After reading the recent catenary question I realized there is no tag for "catenaries", despite it being a specific math topic with a lot of questions on here.  If someone with enough reputation points could create this tag that would be great.

Comment: There is a tag `hyperbolic-functions`.

Comment: Tags are meant to help organize the site, so that it is easier to find questions and answers.  The fact that something is a "specific math topic" is not (by itself) enough to justify the creation of a tag.  What would a [tag:catenary] tag offer that simply searching for the term "catenary" would not?

Comment: A careful study of the linked duplicate target [Tag management 2023](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35451/tag-management-2023) will illustrate the information that customarily accompanies a request for a new tag.  The number of existing Questions for which the new tag is applicable is important, as is some sketch of what scope or even tag wikia is proposed.